# "Contains" method doesn't seem to working the way it should

Tags: c#, contains

I'm trying to see if when a user enters some text it searches the array for any matches, and whatever doesn't match gets removed from the array;

```
string search = textBox1.Text;
for (int i = 0; i < staffUsers.Count; i++)
{
    if (!(staffUsers[i].staff_name.Contains(search)))
    {
        staffUsers.Remove(staffUsers[i]);
    }
}
```

I have some rubbish names in my array 'Rob Dob','Joe Bloggs', 'h h', 'ghg hgh', and if the search variable ended up being 'R', Joe Bloggs would get removed but 'h h' and 'ghg hgh' stay there, but there is no R involved there at all? any reason why>?!

Comment: What is the type of staffUsers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to iterate backwards in order to remove from an array. Every time you remove an item, your array gets smaller. By going backwards, that fact does not matter.

```
string search = textBox1.Text;

for (int i = staffUsers.Count - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
{
    if (!(staffUsers[i].staff_name.Contains(search)))
    {
        staffUsers.Remove(staffUsers[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Argghhhh!!! I knew it was going to be something so minor! Thanks Matt and all others.

Answer (score 6):

The problem with your code is that you are removing items as you iterate over it. You remove an item, but keep iterating, even though the size of the array changes when you remove an item.

You need to reset your i value after you remove something. Alternatively, you need to use a built in to do the heavy lifting:

```
staffUsers.RemoveAll(i => !(i.staff_name.Contains(search)));
```

Uses a tiny LINQ expression to do the work. Remove all items where that predicate matches. `i` represents an item to apply the expression to. If that expression evaluates to true, away it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, whenever you remove an item at index [i], you skip the item at index [i+1]. For example, if your array looks like:

{'Joe Bloggs', 'Rob Dobb', 'h h', 'gafddf'}; i=0

remove Joe Bloggs, which is at position 0.

{Rob Dobb', 'h h', 'gafddf'}; i=1

remove 'h h', which is at position 1

{Rob Dobb', 'gafddf'}; i=2

i is not less than yourArray.Count, so the loop stops. There is no position 2.

The quickest fix is to add i-- if you remove something from index [i]. In your case,

```
staffUsers.Remove(staffUsers[i]);
i--;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In each iteration of the loop, either remove an item or increment the counter, not both operations. Otherwise, you'll skip the next array element whenever you remove an array element:

```
string search = textBox1.Text;
for (int i = 0; i < staffUsers.Count;)
{
    if (!(staffUsers[i].staff_name.Contains(search)))
    {
        staffUsers.Remove(staffUsers[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string search = textBox1.Text;
for (int i = 0; i < staffUsers.Count; i++)
{
    if (!(staffUsers[i].staff_name.Contains(search)))
    {
        staffUsers.Remove(staffUsers[i]);
        // reset the index one stepback
        i--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to solve the above problem is using LINQ.
Following code disentangle above problem.

```
string search = textBox1.Text;
staffUsers= (from user in staffUsers
            where !user.Contains(search)
            select user).ToArray<string>();
```

Note: I assumed staffUsers is array of string.